# How does the universe create more universe ( expand ) out of nothing?

Tags: universe

By the law of conversation of energy, mass and matter, how does the universe get the energy to expand itself, and also expand faster than light!!

Edit :

my main question is that if the matter, energy and mass in universe is constant how does universe keep creating more of it and why? How can something be generated from nothing if the total energy in the universe can't be destroyed nor created?

Comment: Can you add some more details?

Comment: There are several questions on this topic on our sister site, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259759/123208 & the questions linked on that page, especially https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/123208

Comment: You appear to have two questions, and a premise that is irrelevant to either of them. Can you edit to focus on one question. But first check out the physics questions PM 2Ring linked

Comment: @fasterthanlight edited the question

Comment: Why do you think the universe "keeps creating more of it" (I assume "it" means "energy, mass and matter)  The universe is expanding, but it isn't creating more energy, mass or matter.  (it converts some "mass" into  "energy", but really these just different forms of the same thing.)

Comment: @Xcaliber It turns out that it's *really hard* to ask any kind of question about the [metric expansion of space](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~rwest/wikispeedia/wpcd/wp/m/Metric_expansion_of_space.htm) (see also [Expansion of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe)) in Stack Exchange. I have tried several times in Physics SE myself ([1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268353/83380), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251088/83380)) and I still don't understand it at all. Sometimes one gets very theoretical answers with fancy mathematical terms..

Comment: @Xcaliber and sometimes one gets close votes and idle unhelpful comments like "Why do you think..." and close votes. Don't give up! But I recommend you poke around here in Astronomy SE and in Physics SE, look at those linked and lots of other questions and answers, and see if any of that, or anything else on the internet is helpful, then try again with a more specific question, and try to ask about something that you've read by quoting it. For example, unless you can find a source that says more energy is being created, it's not good to use that as a premise of a Stack Exchange question.

Comment: @Xcaliber Metric expansion is a hard concept and I don't understand it, but sometimes the ballon and raisin cake analogies can be at least a little helpful. If you draw clusters of dots for patterns of stars in a few galaxies) on a balloon, then inflate the balloon, the space between stars gets bigger. *But we have to remember that the stars don't also get bigger!* If we put raisins in bread dough, and then let the dough rise and bake it, the raisins are now farther apart. These are imperfect analogies, but they are somewhat helpful.

Comment: I really want to know why the OP thinks that.  It looks like a contradition "if the matter, energy and mass in universe is constant how does universe keep creating more of it"  If it is constant, the universe isn't creating more of it.  If the universe is creating more of it, it isn't constant.  So the question is unclear.  And if the question is unclear it won't get a clear answer.  So this is a helpful comment.  if the OP can respond to the comment and clarify their question it might be answerable, or it might be a dupe, or it might be a simple misconception.